Is there an equivalent of the socketTimeout configuration option for the AwsCrtHttpClient?
In the AWS Java SDKv2, the ApacheHttpClient and UrlConnectionHttpClient both have a socketTimeout configuration option:

socketTimeout(Duration socketTimeout)
The amount of time to wait for data to be transferred over an established, open connection before the connection is timed out.

But I don’t see this option on the AwsCrtHttpClient... is there an equivalent setting for the AwsCrtHttpClient?

This is the equivalent: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/http/crt/ConnectionHealthConfiguration.Builder.html
If you want to emulate the old socket timeout behavior, just set minimumThroughputInBps to 1 and minimumThroughputTimeout to whatever you want your socket timeout to be.  However, you can also make this timeout logic more complex by using a different value for minimumThroughputInBps in which case it will only timeout the connection if the data being received is under the specified threshold.

connectionMacIdleTime looks similar since they both start with open, established connections according to the descriptions.
